# mysql outer join - returning a complete list of records that don't always have entries in a correlated table

Tags: mysql, sql

this is in mysql v. 4.x... i'm sure this is an rookie question but for some reason i can't get figure out the sql to get this to work. here is an approximation of the relevant tables:

```
Item
---
ItemID
```

etc.

```
ItemPerson
--------
PersonID

ItemID

TimeAccessed
```

Let's say I have Item ID's of 1,2,3,4,5

Let's say that I have 1 record in ItemPerson: `{'JohnDoe',1,'12:00PM'}`

I have a PersonName as input. I want returned a list of all items, including the time that item was accessed.  If that item was not accessed by the given PersonName, I want NULL for the time.

I've tried the following:

```
SELECT i.*, ip.TimeAccessed
FROM Item i LEFT OUTER JOIN ItemPerson ip
ON i.ItemID = ip.ItemID
WHERE (ip.PersonName = 'JohnDoe' OR ip.PersonName IS NULL)
```

I get the expected results for 'JohnDoe'...  All items are returned and ItemID 1 has a time.

If I change 'JohnDoe' to 'JaneDoe', I only get ItemID's 2-5 but I want my query to return all items, just with NULL for all the times.

Comment: the left is what is limiting the JaneDoe results. If you want them all, try 'Outer join' (without Left). If you want only relevant records, then use left or right inner joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LEFT JOINs can be tricky in these circumstances. You'll want to move the person condition into the ON clause; otherwise you are getting the items associated with that person or no one at all. (Logically speaking, optimizer aside, the WHERE occurs after the JOIN).

Comment: ugh. yes, of course! knew i was having a brain lapse.  that worked perfectly.  i'll mark this as soon as the system lets me.